# WinForm Event-Handlers activating too slow

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'de like you to take a look at this code:
I have a Button named Button1.

```
    private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
```

This code works but the problem is there is a very small delay. About 1/2 second delay on changing the colors. I've tried the same thing in WPF and there is absolutely no delay in that. Basically I want the Mouse event to fire as quickly as possible.

In what ways can i accomplish that task ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the MouseEnter event rather than MouseHover - the latter is fired 'after a delay' because Windows can't tell that the mouse is hovering unless it has been stationary for a short while.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've literally researched for a whole day and tried to come up with so many different approach because of this problem, however the solution was so... simple.
You saved me a lot of time

Comment: My pleasure - glad to have been of service.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `button1.Invalidate(false)` will result in redrawing the control within the next frame. Place this line right after your color-changing code and see if it works.